# Alfresco share customization - adding styles

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I would like to change primary button style from `Save and Close` button to `Task completed` button.

**Where are css classes added to DOM elements?**
I know i can edit `task-list-toolbar.js` to delete `alf-primary-button` class from `Save and close` button but how can I add class to `Task completed` button?

I have checked `transitions.ftl` and `transitions.js` but there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

transitions.ftl and transitions.js , this 2 files are responsible for rendering the buttons.Buttons are rendered dynamically.So you will not find static text inside it.If required You can extend same file for your workflow task and customize it as per your requirement.

Comment: Yeah, but somewhere has to be the code responsible for the dynamic rendering. And inside, the code which adds css classes... Anyway, so you suggest, what file should I change to achieve my goal?